# GPUImageStillCamera output image resolution

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm trying to take photo from camera with GPUImage framework. Use standard [implementation](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#capturing-and-filtering-a-still-photo). But my output image has too low resolution - {640, 852}. Is there way to get more higher resolution?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `-capturePhotoProcessedUpToFilter:` and not just trying to pull an image from a filter using `-imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a while back.  It was the way the `AVCaptureSession` was setup.

Try initializing the camera with the following:

```
GPUImageStillCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc]
            initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
                   cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
```